# css positioning absolute not working as expected

Tags: css, css-position

I am learning CSS and was fiddling with CSS position property. As I understand, the `position:absolute` will place the element with respect to the browser window and all the elements below will be pushed before the element with position:absolute. But when I run the fiddle, I see that by default the element is placed below the `h1` tag and not at the top left corner of the window. Please let me know where I am going wrong in understanding. Below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Just some text to check the css positioning in the browserJust some text to check the css positioning in the browserJust some text to check the css positioning in the browserJust some text to check the css positioning in the browserJust some text to check the css positioning in the browserJust some text to check the css positioning in the browserJust some text to check the css positioning in the browserJust some text to check the css</h1>
    <div style="position:relative; background-color:green; width:20px;padding:10px;">
      <div style="position:absolute;background-color:red;padding:10px">
        <span>value</span>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Plnkr link - [Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/YEH3fj9jbY0s2HdLWpTe?p=preview)

Comment: no, it'll be absolute to the `pos:relative` you have above it. your absolute div would only be absolute to the browser window if no other parent/container elements had positioning on them.

Answer (score 5):

`position:absolute` positions the element relative to its nearest positioned ancestor element (in this case, its `position:relative` parent div). Use `position:fixed` in order to position relative to the window.

Answer (score 1):

You need some positioning for the div.

```
left:100px;
top:200px;
```

Or you can use relational positioning as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `position: relative` from the parent div.  The absolute position will be based off of it, as it is the nearest relatively positioned element.  If you remove it, it will be positioned relative to the html body.  You also have to position the div, or it will default to its flowed position.

```
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

Code:

```
<div style="position: relative; background-color:green; width:20px; padding:10px;">
  <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left: 0px; background-color:red; padding:10px">
    <span>value</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Snippet:

```css
#outer {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
 <h1>Just some text to check the css positioning in the browser. Just some text to check the css positioning in the browser. Just some text to check the css positioning in the browser. Just some text to check the css positioning in the browser. Just some text to check the css positioning in the browser. Just some text to check the css positioning in the browser. Just some text to check the css positioning in the browser. Just some text to check the css</h1>
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <span>value</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I remove the `green` div position from 'position:relative' to default position also there is no change. Why is that now the element is not positioned relative to the window?

Comment: Did you add positioning to the element?  i.e. `top: 0px; left: 0px`?  If not, it will maintain its default flowed position.

Comment: Got it  thanks. But when the element is positioned relative to the browser window with `position:absolute` it overlaps on the existing elements since the element will be removed from the normal flow and be placed relative to the browser window and does not push the current element. So, what practical purpose does it solve and when will it be useful.

Comment: That's exactly what absolute positioning is for.  Or more specifically, it is to position something absolutely with regard to the nearest relative element, ignoring the normal flow.  You are saying, "Ignore the flow, put it where I tell you to."  You wouldn't usually position something absolutely to the body from within a bunch of nested objects.  But, there are lots of circumstances when you want to position things absolutely.  Menus, tooltips, modal dialogs, special tables, image alignment, etc.  Without absolute positioning, elements would push each other around no matter what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Position is absolute compared to the first parent with relative position!

In your example, red div has an absolute position compared to the green div.

If you want to have an element at the top of the window you can use position:fixed.

If you want to have an element at the top of the body, you have to remove the relative position of the green div!

Cheers!