# Can't move logo position

Tags: html, css, position

New to web design, so this is probably really badly written code. This may be something very obvious, but no matter what i change in the css of the logo, i can't get it to move? I need to move the logo down.

```css
.header {
    padding: 10px 16px;
    background-color: darkred;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px black;
    font-family: arial;
    position: relative;
    height: 90px;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x90" width=300 height=90>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're trying to use `absolute` or `relative` positioning, don't use `float`, use `left`, `right`, `top`, and/or `bottom` to set the position of the item.

Comment: Also, not sure if you accidentally truncated the closing `</div>` tag for `#myHeader` only from the snippet or your original code, but if it is the latter you're going to have problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css positioning absolute not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346041/css-positioning-absolute-not-working-as-expected) [Ansver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35346174/11151040)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to move the logo somewhere in the website, I think you should not use float, it will attached to somewhere position that you assign them to and because of that you can't move your div freely. You must use `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`. At the same time it will replace `margin-top` for you. Also you should contain `background-repeat: no-repeat`, `background-size: contain`. So your logo won't repeat if you scroll down. And last, you should set margin: 0 auto for they not sticky to other div if you have any.

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px; //For example
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```